# How would I go about solving this cipher?

Tags: classical-cipher, substitution-cipher

I am not sure this is the right place to post this... recently I was given the following image by my friend in the context of a game we play together. Please note the characters at the bottom.

I would like to figure out what the characters say, but I am not even sure how I would go about it. I suspect it's some sort of cipher where each symbol represents one specific letter.

What techniques could I use to start trying to figure out what the characters say?

[image: Frog with candle on back plus floating key above. Cipher below all this]

Comment: I'm sorry but this is indeed not the right place for this.

Comment: Probably that "lemon writing" thing where you hold heat to the paper and stuff appears https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_ink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I suspect it's some sort of cipher where each symbol represents one specific letter."

If your assumption is true then I would recommend [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis), even though this cipher text is rather short.